# Flask throws error in run_wsgi_app function

Tags: python, flask

I am setting up my first Flask application and i have followed the documenation from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlite3/.

My app.py code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, g, render_template, request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

DATABASE = 'sql_db.db'

@app.route("/")

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def index():
    return 'It works!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the index function, I will do some queries and render a template but I can't get this basic code to work. I get the following error:

```
File ".../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) 
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a Connection.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `get_db()` is view function (because there is `@app.route("/")` before this function) and - as you see in error - it has to return string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable - but you return `db` which is `Connection`. OR you put `@app.route("/")` in wrong and it has to be before `def index():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `@app.route("/")` in wrong place. It has to be before `def index()`.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return 'It works!'
```

You can even see it in doc in your link: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlite3/

Answer (score -1):

this here works for me, let me know if it works.

Code:

```
from random import randint
from time import strftime
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from sklearn import tree
import mysql.connector
import pymysql

DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='', template_folder='templates')
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.instance_path, '/', ''
# app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SjdnUends821Jsdlkvxh391ksdODnejdDw'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'owieihfwuefgw98rgw8o73rg7wgfwfgw87'

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return render_template('index.html', name = "nothing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

> I think you need (app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)) but i'm not
>   sure

Happy codeing